# /proc/cpuinfo fails to detect CPU model name

Tags: linux, central-processing-unit

We have a server which has four **Intel Xeon E7 4860** CPU. Strangely, the model name  in `/proc/cpuinfo` contains a `000` string instead of `E4860`.

Incorrect model name:

```
model name  : Genuine Intel(R) CPU             000  @ 2.27GHz
```

Correct model name:

```
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5620  @ 2.40GHz
```

The servers runs Arch Linux with kernel 3.2.12

BTW, I digged into kernel source code and found the relevant information are retrieved using Intel CPUID instruction.

Comment: It might help you to search for "Linux kernel misdetects Intel Xeon as Genuine Intel" rather than focus on the /proc/cpuinfo API.

Answer (score 1):

Try the dmidecode command to compare results.

Comment: no, dmidecode has the same result as /proc/cpuinfo

Answer (score 0):

How about the `lshw` command?  Does that give you the model number?

Comment: no, the result is same as /proc/cpuinfo. This is because lshw internally parse /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: you are right. i guess /dev/cpu/*/cpuid will be the same deal then. i wonder if it is a kernel bug or something with the hardware itself. what if you boot up a livecd/liveusb with a different distro or even different OS, say windows 7?